# Genexus Ev3 - Procedure variavel externa

Tags: genexus

Preciso criar uma procedure em GX que será chamada por uma aplicação desenvolvida em outra plataforma.

A procedure do Genexus precisa receber uma variável, e se possível retornar.

Alguma orientação sobre troca de variaveis e chamada externa para uma procedure desenvolvida em Genexus ?

Gx Ev.3 - Java Win.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Felipe,

Obrigado pela resposta.

Na verdade a procedure que pretendo criar esta consumindo um web service.

Estou criando a rotina de client do ws no Genexus Ev3 Java, essa procedure será utilizada por objetos gerados em outras versões do Genexus (2.1,7,9) e com outros geradores (.NET,Visual Fox)
Sendo necessário realizar a troca de parâmetros, pelo menos na chamada da proc, no retorno posso gravar em arquivo texto.

Acredito que o mais provável será realizar a chamada a procedure client (ev3) na linguagem nativa do gerador (.Net, VF), tem alguma outra solução ?

E como preparar essa procedure para receber parametros externos ? Com parm(out:) ?

Vou realizar testes conforme orientação do link:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Calling+a+GeneXus+generated+program+from+other+Environments,

At.

Filipe

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia!

Existem n formas de fazer o que solicitou, porem a que eu mais recomendo é por meio de webservice, segue link do wiki:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?WebService

Se a sua necessidade for chamar sua procedure como um programa externo, você pode utilzar o comando shell para chama-la por outros programas:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Shell+Function

como sua procedure é java você pode fazer:

```
    &msg = "java -cp gxclassr.jar;seudrivedebancodedados.jar; suaclassjava parm1 parm2 parm3" 
//(parâmetros sempre separados por espaços).

    &ret = shell(&msg)
```

a unica desvantagem do shell é que ele não retorna mensagens, então você precisaria gravar o retorno no banco ou em arquivo texto como citou acima.
boa sorte, se precisar de mais ajuda não hesite em mandar-me um e-mail.

Espero que lhe ajude.

Atenciosamente, Felipe.

Comment: Para que você seja notificado, comento ou respondo ? Respondi com mais detalhes.